# Using jQuery methods on event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check specific attributes of event target during `click` event:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e) {  
    console.log(e.target.attr('class'));
});
```

This results in error in browser console:

> main.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: e.target.attr is not a function

Isn't `event.target` a jQuery object too?

Comment: also console.log($(this).attr('class'));

Comment: @KapitulaAlexey No, `event.target` can be different than `this`

Answer (score 26):

`e.target` is not a jQuery object by default, it is a DOM element. You have to cast it:

```
$(e.target).attr('class')
```

Working example:

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">click me</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to mix with javascript and jquery code ,because it is hard to handle or understand .

```
$('div').on('click', function(e) {  
    //console.log(e.target.className);    javascript
    console.log($(this).attr('class')); //jquery
});
```

Comment: event.target does not equals $(this)

Comment: Yes jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript ,So why we used JS code again without needing

Comment: No, jQuery doesn't make JavaScript easier, it make DOM manipulation easier. So there is nothing *mixed*, jQuery *is* JavaScript. jQuery is not a decent programming language. And as said before, `this` is wrong too.